# Stream live video to Android and iPhone smartphones

Tags: mobile, video-streaming

I am developing a live video streaming solution for a client with the following requirements:
- Stream live video to high-end Android and iPhone devices, from a mobile-optimized web app (NOT native apps)
- The video should not be full screen but partial screen, so that other HTML content can be displayed below the video

So my question is, what is the video format/technology that allows live video streaming in both devices? I've heard about HLS but I am not sure it plays in both devices.

And also, is there a way to prevent the video from going full screen? I've come across this in SO http://broken-links.com/tests/video/, but it's for on demand video. Could it also apply for live video streaming?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should set `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` attribute of your `UIWebView` instance to `YES` for iOS.
From Apple's UIWebView reference page:

> **allowsInlineMediaPlayback**
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether HTML5 videos play inline or
>   use the native full-screen controller.
>
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsInlineMediaPlayback Discussion The
>   default value on iPhone is NO.
>
> In order for video to play inline, not only does this property need to
>   be set on the view, but the video element in the HTML document must
>   also include the webkit-playsinline attribute.

For `Android`, AFAIK default behaviour of Android's `WebView` is not triggering media player with fullscreen. You should be able to use `WebView` as is.

You can get information about supported video formats with those links:

[iOS Media Layer Supported Video Formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html)

[Android Supported Video Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

There are two major industry standards, I guess it won't be a problem if I understand your concerns correctly.

Hope that helps.